# Update SQL com Objeto Modelo

Tags: php

Eu tenho um método que recebe um modelo com alguns campos preenchidos, quero fazer o update apenas destes campos, meu método atual esta assim:

```
    public function atualizar($aluno,$email)
{
    $sql = new Sql();

    if ($aluno->email == null){
        $aluno->email = $email;
    }
    if ($aluno->senha != null){
        $hash = Bcrypt::hash($aluno->senha);
        $aluno->senha = $hash;
    }

    try {
        return $sql->query("UPDATE tb_alunos SET nome= :nome,sobrenome=:sobrenome, email=:email,senha=:senha,unidadelocal=:unidadelocal,unidadecurricular=:unidadecurricular,diapreparacao=:diapreparacao,liberadoexercicio=:liberadoexercicio,token=:token,sub=:sub WHERE email=:email", $aluno);

    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
        return false;
    }


}
```

Ele atualiza, usando o modelo, porem quando quando não há um dado em algum campo do modelo, ele sobrescreve o valor que estava como nulo, e esse que é o problema, tenho que atualizar apenas os campos passados

EDIT

`UPDATE tb_alunos SET sobrenome=:sobrenome, unidadecurricular=:unidadecurricular WHERE email=:email`

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar a string da query de acordo com os valores que são enviados. Por exemplo:

```
    public function atualizar($aluno,$email)
{
    $sql = new Sql();

    $query = "UPDATE tb_alunos SET "; // string inicial

    if ($aluno->email == null){
        $aluno->email = $email;
        $query .= "email=:email, "; // concatena o email que será alterado
    }
    if ($aluno->senha != null){
        $hash = Bcrypt::hash($aluno->senha);
        $aluno->senha = $hash;
        $query .= "senha=:senha, "; // concatena a senha que será alterada
    }

    // análise dos outros campos

    $query = substr($query , 0, -2); // aqui ele apaga a ultima vírgula e o espaço
    $query .= " WHERE email=:email"; // concatena o final da query

    try {
        return $sql->query($query , $aluno);

    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: @IgorOliveira tenta fazer com a edição que eu fiz no final do post.

Comment: nao funciona a query fica assim: UPDATE tb_alunos SET nome=:, sobrenome=:sobrenome, unidadelocal=:, unidadecurricular=:unidadecurricular, diapreparacao=:, liberadoexercicio=:, token=:, sub=: WHERE email=:email

Comment: Acho que seria interessante então passar o objeto copiado, e alterar apenas os dados para update

Comment: @IgorOliveira Também acho! Voltamos a primeira ETAPA! rsrsrs

Comment: @IgorOliveira apaguei minhas edições pois elas não irão ajudar. boa sorte.

Comment: Obrigado por tentar